# gdb and strncmp, register value stored?

Tags: gdb

Below is my code (test.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

 char passwd[] = "pass";

 if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: %s <given-password>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
 }

 if (!strncmp(passwd, argv[1],4)) {
        printf("Green light!\n");
        return 1;
 }

 printf("Red light!\n");
 return 0;
}
```

I compiled using :

```
  gcc -o test test.c

    And I started debugger: `gdb ./test`
    (gdb) disassemble main
    Dump of assembler code for function main:
    0x08048404 <main+0>:    lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
    ......
    0x08048456 <main+82>:   mov    0x4(%edx),%eax
    0x08048459 <main+85>:   add    $0x4,%eax
    0x0804845c <main+88>:   mov    (%eax),%eax
    0x0804845e <main+90>:   movl   $0x4,0x8(%esp)
    0x08048466 <main+98>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
    0x0804846a <main+102>:  lea    -0x9(%ebp),%eax
    0x0804846d <main+105>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
    0x08048470 <main+108>:  call   0x8048318 <strncmp@plt>
    0x08048475 <main+113>:  test   %eax,%eax
    0x08048477 <main+115>:  jne    0x804848e <main+138>
    0x08048479 <main+117>:  movl   $0x804859c,(%esp)
    0x08048480 <main+124>:  call   0x8048308 <puts@plt>
    0x08048485 <main+129>:  movl   $0x1,-0x18(%ebp)
 ...........
    0x080484a8 <main+164>:  pop    %ebp
    0x080484a9 <main+165>:  lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
    0x080484ac <main+168>:  ret
    End of assembler dump.
```

I set breakpoint at main+108 and run prog!

```
    (gdb) break *main+108
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048470
    (gdb) run p@ss
    Starting program: /etc/hien/test p@ss

    Breakpoint 1, 0x08048470 in main ()
    eax            0xbfffe9ff       -1073747457
    ecx            0xbfffea20       -1073747424
    edx            0xbfffea20       -1073747424
    ebx            0xaebff4 11452404
    esp            0xbfffe9e0       0xbfffe9e0
    ebp            0xbfffea08       0xbfffea08
    esi            0x994ca0 10046624
    edi            0x0      0
    eip            0x8048470        0x8048470 <main+108>
    eflags         0x282    [ SF IF ]
    cs             0x73     115
    ss             0x7b     123
    ds             0x7b     123
    es             0x7b     123
    fs             0x0      0
    gs             0x33     51
    (gdb) x/s $eax
    0xbfffe9ff:      "pass"
    (gdb) x/s $ecx
    0xbfffea20:      "\002"
    (gdb)
```

Which register can show value of "argv[1]"?
Please help me!Thanks!

Comment: Is there some reason you need the register (it might not be in a register) ? Just compile with the `-g` option and issuing "print argv[1]` in gdb is not enough) ?

Comment: Where value of argv[1] store if not use -g option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calling convention should be that all parameters are pushed to the stack. So try

```
(gdb) x/s *(0 + (void**)$esp)
# should show "pass"
(gdb) x/s *(1 + (void**)$esp)
# should show argv[1]
(gdb) x/d *(2 + (void**)$esp)
# should show 4
```